# How can I add an image to my JavaScript/JQuery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to make a simple browser-based quiz that has a picture as the question and text answers or vice-versa (it's a sign language quiz) and I found a quiz template online that seems to be working good, but for the life of me I have no idea how to add a picture to the question.

Code:
http://codepen.io/jchamill/pen/garoqg

JS Code:

```
$('#quiz').quiz({
  //resultsScreen: '#results-screen',
  //counter: false,
  //homeButton: '#custom-home',
  counterFormat: 'Question %current of %total',
  questions: [
    {
      'q': 'Is jQuery required for this plugin?', // This is where I'd like the photo to be.
      'options': [
        'Yes',
        'No'
      ],
      'correctIndex': 0,
      'correctResponse': 'Good job, that was obvious.',
      'incorrectResponse': 'Well, if you don\'t include it, your quiz won\'t work'
    },
    {
      'q': 'How do you use it?',
      'options': [
        'Include jQuery, that\'s it!',
        'Include jQuery and the plugin javascript.',
        'Include jQuery, the plugin javascript, the optional plugin css, required markup, and the javascript configuration.'
      ],
      'correctIndex': 2,
      'correctResponse': 'Correct! Sounds more complicated than it really is.',
      'incorrectResponse': 'Come on, it\'s not that easy!'
    },
    {
      'q': 'The plugin can be configured to require a perfect score.',
      'options': [
        'True',
        'False'
      ],
      'correctIndex': 0,
      'correctResponse': 'You\'re a genius! You just set allowIncorrect to true.',
      'incorrectResponse': 'Why you have no faith!? Just set allowIncorrect to true.'
    },
    {
      'q': 'How do you specify the questions and answers?',
      'options': [
        'MySQL database',
        'In the HTML',
        'In the javascript configuration'
      ],
      'correctIndex': 2,
      'correctResponse': 'Correct! Refer to the documentation for the structure.',
      'incorrectResponse': 'Wrong! Do it in the javascript configuration. You might need to read the documentation.'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is intended to help you when you can't figure out a solution despite trying everything, you need learn front-end web development for this. Its a pretty simple one.
kindly go through the respective tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fork and change the plugin itself. You want to look in `src/jquery.quiz.js` and alter the `setup` function. specifically the part between line 68 and 79:

```
quizHtml += '<div id="questions">';
$.each(questions, function(i, question) {
    quizHtml += '<div class="question-container">';
    quizHtml += '<p class="question">' + question.q + '</p>';
    quizHtml += '<ul class="answers">';
    $.each(question.options, function(index, answer) {
        quizHtml += '<li><a href="#" data-index="' + index + '">' + answer + '</a></li>';
    });
    quizHtml += '</ul>';
    quizHtml += '</div>';
});
quizHtml += '</div>';
```